# Simple 3D scene visualisation data format

Tags: c++, 3d, formatting, visualization, file-format

My PhD project revoles around simulating the paths of photons through objects of different optical properties. My code has classes which create ccd images etc, but it would be much more useful to be able to create a simple rendering of the 3D objects and the paths the photons take through them.

I've written an opengl system for viewing such a scene, but it would be much better if I could use something much more lightweight where I could simply specify the vertices of an object, and then a photon path as a list of connected vertices.

Exporting all the data and then visualising it in another program isn't ideal, as things like mesh transformations need to be taken into account, and I'd rather avoid exporting several new mesh objects just to import them all into another program.

What I essentially need is to be able to create the three dimensional equivalent of a svg image. Does such a '3D scene' file format with a simple visualiser exist?

I write in C++ on MacOS, though I'd prefer to avoid using a visualisation library. I appreciate that what I'm asking for is rather niece and picky, but that's why I'm asking the internet as someone might have come across a similar need for such a tool.

[image: An example of the opengl visualisation]

Comment: Could you give an example what this visualization should look like? It'll be hard to recommend a file format without knowing which capabilities your visualization will require…

Comment: X3D/VRML perhaps?

Comment: @MichaelKenzel I've attached an example from my opengl program

Comment: gLTF ... perhaps?